# Locate File in Slution Explorer in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to locate the current a file in the Visual Studio's "Solution Explorer"?

I don't want to always track the current file. But I would like to locate at demand the current file in the explorer.

I found a way, using macros(http://goo.gl/ejMx4D), but macros are not available in VS 2013/12.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this button or the shortcut Ctrl+[, S:

[image: Solution Explorer toolbar]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean find the path where is stored some file, just select the file in solution explorer and next go to properties window. There is the full path of currently selected file.